# Joi Validation Accepts undefined When Required

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation, joi

I have a validation issue I am hitting while using Joi. I have a set of number fields that begin with a value of `undefined` but are ultimately required. However, Joi still accepts the `undefined` values upon submit.

`expenses: Joi.number().min(0).max(9999999).required()`

I have found that once I load the form and click submit, the values are accepted. However, if I type into a field, say `1` and then backspace to remove it, then the field does error on submit.

Any way I can get the `undefined` to trigger the error on the number field with the initial submit?

Comment: When you submit the empty form have you inspected the values being passed to Joi? Ultimately there's nothing wrong with your schema, it will indeed stop `undefined` and `null` so are you positive nothing's changing the data between the form and Joi?

Comment: Long story short, yes, that was the issue. Joi was validating different values than what I was expecting. Thanks!